# Postfix configuration CentOS 7

Tags: postfix, centos7

For configuring the Postfix service for my CentOS 7 servers, I edited the */etc/posfix/main.cf* and gave all required parameters. After the restart it shows these errors:

```
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 ~]# sudo systemctl status postfix
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-04-18 02:51:26 UTC; 32min ago
  Process: 11874 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4912 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4910 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4907 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=75)
 Main PID: 973 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Apr 18 02:51:25 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 postfix/sendmail[4909]: warning: valid_hostname: invalid character 32(decimal): centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01  mydoma...es = all
Apr 18 02:51:25 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 aliasesdb[4907]: newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: invalid character 32(decimal): centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01  m...es = all
Apr 18 02:51:25 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 aliasesdb[4907]: newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: centos-s...es = all
Apr 18 02:51:25 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 postfix/sendmail[4909]: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: centos-s-1vcp...es = all
Apr 18 02:51:25 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 postfix[4912]: warning: valid_hostname: invalid character 32(decimal): centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01  mydomain = livs...es = all
Apr 18 02:51:25 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 postfix[4912]: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams...es = all
Apr 18 02:51:26 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 systemd[1]: postfix.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 18 02:51:26 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Apr 18 02:51:26 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 systemd[1]: Unit postfix.service entered failed state.
Apr 18 02:51:26 centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 systemd[1]: postfix.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01 ~]#
```

I already changed the hostname of the system to smtp.livsite.com but it also shows the error, so I reverted back to the initial stage.  How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

In your postfix warning:

`warning: valid_hostname: invalid character 32(decimal)`

complains us that the hostname contains space character(0x20 = 32 in decimal).
Check your hostname configuration whether space character is used or not.

Another complain:

`fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams...es = all`

also complains myhostname in /etc/postfix/main.cf.

Check and Try:
`myhostname = centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01.$mydomain`

or replace $mydomain as fixed string following:

`myhostname = centos-s-1vcpu-3gb-ams3-01.your.domain`

Comment: whitespace not used in the hostname. but still the same error after changing it to a new hostname. I think it may be  other reason

Comment: Looking at the formatting of the error message, my guess is a trailing space at the end. Check the /etc/hosts file if you ever get this (or any other character - e.g. 34 is an unwanted quotation mark).